axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 in trimesh
i am facing axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
while calculating in the following API of trimesh
locations, index_ray, index_tri = mesh.ray.intersects_location(
        ray_origins=ray_origins,
        ray_directions=ray_directions)

ray_origins = np.array(Mesh_object.center_mass)
ray_directions = np.array([-1, 0, 0])

origin is center of mesh and direction is in -x direction, what could be the issue.
